# Removing chapter numbers from section headings in memoir

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir

I don't want the chapter number in the section headings:

[image: example 1]

That can be achieved by `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}`, which works fine as long as one doesn't have more than one chapter at a time:

[image: example 2]

Because then the section counter also doesn't get reset in the next chapter, which of course is also odd.

Now I found two solutions for that, both redefining `\thesection`, see the following example:

[image: example 3]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\counterwithout{section}{chapter} %remove chapter number from headings
%\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section in first chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{First section in second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Commented out line 3 seemed to work, but looking at `memoir.cls` I saw the definition of `\thesection` differed, so I adapted it and it also seems to work, but I'm not sure if it doesn't have any side effects, or if there would be a better way of doing it.

Also so far (before glueing my chapters together) I had used the `\counterwithout` approach. If I don't do that anymore, would I get chapter numbers appearing in other places other than the section headings? Or will that be taken care of by the redefinition of `\thesection`?

Comment: I'd just do `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}`. I do not quite understand what you are asking for in the two paragraphs after the MWE.

Comment: @daleif I'll go with your suggestion then, if you consider it safe, means that it won't break anything at other places. This was also my worry about removing the `\counterwithout` from my style file, that suddenly chapter numbers would appear in places not currently on my radar. Also I was wondering what the difference was between `\arabic{section}` and `\@arabic\c@section`.

Comment: @muk.li `\c@countername` is the macro behind `countername`, so you do not need the @. The thing to be carefull about is of course any reference to chapter 1 section 1, outside chapter 1, then one need to remember the `Chapter 1` prefix.

Comment: It is used in \sectionmark and \thesubsection.  It appears in the \tableofcontents, \caption, fancyhdr and possibly a number of packages which use \csname the#1\endcsname.

Answer (score 6):

Using

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

is similar to

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
```

so use the former. Sectional numbering is defined recursively by default, meaning that if its removed from `\section`, it'll be removed from `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, ...

However, the chapter number may show elsewhere still, like in the captions of floats (like figure and table), since that's the default setting for [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir).